# Node.js/Firebase - listener never triggers

Tags: node.js, firebase, raspberry-pi, firebase-realtime-database

I'm running Node.js and Firebase on several Raspberry Pi systems to prototype some cloud functionality for a client. I'm running Node.js on the Raspberry Pis and on my PC, a Mac.

I created an experimental program which successfully runs on my Mac, where I simulate different system id's and names.

**This program is exactly the same on both Rpi and Mac, but this function behaves differently:**

```
systemsRef.child(sysID).once('value', function(snapshot) {
    var exists = (snapshot.val() !== null);
    console.log("Snapshot key is: " + snapshot.key);
    console.log("Snapshot value   is: " + snapshot.val());
}, function(error){
  console.log("There was an error looking up " + sysID + ": " + error);
});
```

`systemsRef` is from:

```
var db = admin.database();
var root = db.ref("/");
var systems = root.child("systems/");
```

`sysID` is a `String` which is a unique name, which I encrypt from various (simulated for now) hardware components + user input. (User === in this case, me.) So I'm able to verify a new row is created in Firebase by looking at the Firebase Console. ***This row insertion/creation never, ever happens when running code from Raspberry Pi, but happens everytime I "connect" a new system from my Mac.***

`systems` is a simple table of key:value pairs, where `key` is the unique system id, and `value` is the unique system name.

Again, just to be very clear, this works perfectly on my Mac, but NEVER on my Raspberry Pi, using the same code. (Yes, I've removed any system dependencies, hence simulated hardware. Which means I'm just making up a random `String`.)

On the Raspberry Pi, I never even see console output from "Snapshot ... ", **nor** is there an error looking up the system ID.

For the experiment I'm using `firebase-admin`, and have the same credentials (for now) on my Raspberry Pi and Mac, which I have painstakingly verified.

Did I miss something? Why is this simple listener never triggered on Raspberry Pi?

Versions:
Node: "v6.9.4",
firebase-admin: "4.0.4"